# (PulseAudio) Make Built-in Audio Analog Stereo loop another device

Tags: pulseaudio

> TLDR: How do I make Build-in Audio Analog Stereo loop another output device?

[image]

I want to isolate some sounds from my computer to only record those, but I want to still be able to hear everything.

```
TeamSpeak ═════╦════> Built-in Analog Audio Stereo
               ^
Game ══════════╩════> OBS
```

> Game Audio goes to Build-in Analog Audio Stereo and my OBS Output Device
>
> TeamSpeak only goes to Build-in Analog Audio Stereo

I can already change the program's device in PulseAudio, I just need to route my `obs` Output Source to my `Built-in Analog Audio Stereo` Source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want a new sink that can be selected for Games, which forwards to two other sinks.

Create a null sink:

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=games sink_properties=device.description=Games
```

and add two loopbacks from the monitor output of that sink to the sinks you want:

```
pacmd load-module module-loopback source="games.monitor" sink="name_of_built_in_stereo_sink"
pacmd load-module module-loopback source="games.monitor" sink="name_of_obs_sink
```

You can get the names with

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
```

and omit the angular brackets.

Try on the commandline first, then add to Pulseaudio initialization files when it works the way you want.